# MongoDB: Is it OK to use a second objectID in a document to use for concurrency check on update?

Tags: c#, mongodb, concurrency, asp.net-mvc-2

Is it OK to use a second objectID in a document to use to test concurrency on an update?

Project: Microsoft MVC2 / C# / Mongo 1.6 / 10Gen C# driver (v0.9.0)

I'm trying to wrap my head around concurrency issues (and NOSQL repository). This is my first project outside of a relational database and I don't know what the practice is around concurrency with Mongo.

Past projects (SQL Server) wrapped concurrency check around a timestamp column/

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the MongoDB docs have a whole [page on concurrency](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Atomic+Operations).

The big key here is really *"what type of concurrency do you want?"* Concurrency has a ton of edge cases that you really need to consider.

The concept of using _id + timestamp can definitely work in MongoDB (or any form of unique *"this was updated"* key). EDIT: Please check out this doc on "[findAndModify](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/findAndModify+Command)" which is probably what you want.

MongoDB has a whole host of cool concurrency features centered around how it does updates. In particular, please see this section on [Update Modifiers](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-ModifierOperations). These special operations are *"atomic on a single document"* and they tend to handle a lot of common cases.

Want to increment a variable? Use `$inc`, it will even create the field if it doesn't exist. Have an array of stuff and want to add something only if it doesn't exist? Use the `$addToSet` command. Mongo has a whole host of such array operations.

These are not quite at the level of _id+timestamp, but they do handle several common cases for concurrency control.

Comment: Is this answer still current? Or does the latest version on Mongo help us out here?

Comment: @jimmy_terra, I sadly don't know the answer to this one. They specify MongoDB 1.6 in the question, so it's technically correct under those specific circumstances. Maybe this needs to be tagged differently to highlight the obsolescence of the questions itself?